# Python UDP packets

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, packet

When you receive data from a UDP socket in python does it give you a single datagram chunk or does it put multiple chunks together?

Is there a way to get only one UDP packet at a time?

Comment: You are guaranteed to get exactly one UDP packet per successful recv() call.

Comment: One other question, what happens if you call the recv function and your bytes is smaller than the packet size?

Comment: In that case, recv() will copy only as many bytes as can fit into your buffer (i.e. the number you specified) and the remaining bytes of the packet will be lost/inaccessible.